# how to silently extract winzip self extractor without progress bar

Tags: .net, winzip

I am running Winzip Self extractor file from .net by passing a command line argument "/auto" so that the installation goes silently.
However i dont want to show the UI/Progress during the installation.
Can anyone guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [`Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) call to start it try to call it with [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx).

Comment: @Sathish then use some other technique or write a custom SFX module (needs C or assembler!)...